# Alcohol tolerance of wild yeasts

Tags: wild-yeast

Here's a question... I have made a cider with wild yeast (whatever was on those apples), and after fermenting it out, I used the same yeast to ferment a session mead (OG~1.060, FG~1.004, ABV~7.3%). It gave a really cool and interesting touch to the mead (much better then original cider).

So, after that I've been thinking, about making a stronger mead. Just out of curiosity, what could be the tolerance of those wild yeasts?

I kinda can guess, that it can go up to 15% (as most of the Saccharomyces), but it would be interesting to find out, what exact strain was growing on the apples (isolated to the Northern California region), Saccharomyces paradoxus?

Comment: I don't think anyone here will have any better idea about strain on your apples that you do. My only hint - with each consecutive batch alcohol tolerance increases. I successfully fermented14% beer with strain that had 12% tolerance in first batch.

Answer (score 1):

Yeast strains can go to 20+% ABV, but it all depends on the strain. I had a 14% yeast ferment a beer to ~22%!

The only way to identify the strain is to send it a lab (unless you have the tools and knowledge). The problem with wild yeast is that you will have many strains, not just one. Bacteria will also be present.